# Does element preserve its position regardless of screen size?

Tags: android

Let's say I have a background with red circle in it, and I want to position 2 buttons like on the image.

[image]

I am doing position on 160dpi HVGA screen resolution (480x320) emulator.

Will these element remain its position on all screens? They are positioned one above another in 2 `RelativeViews` inside `LayoutView` container.

As documentation says that width/height is caclucated based on 160dpi screen, I came to conclusion that this is the way to achieve this. If I am wrong, what is the right way.

Comment: It depends on how you are positioning these items.  Are you doing so in XML layouts, or in code?  Please post code referencing what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I position them in the XML layouts.

Comment: Could you please post the layouts? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to accomplish what you are asking (I think) is to ensure you have graphics for all of the different screen dpis.

You can do this by creating folders

```
drawable
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
```

in your /res folder.

This lets you use specific resources for different dpis, and guarantees the view will look right (after testing) for any screen density.

I suggest looking over the [Android documentation for supporting different screens types](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and the taking a look at [this section in particular](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see. So if my image resolution for mdpi is 80x80 dp, how will I count the size for ldpi or hdpi?

Comment: Check the documentation, it has generic and specific answers for exactly what you're asking for all situations